# memory exhausted and no new connections came from application iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, memory

I have a serious problem in the server we are using.

Every 10 or 15 days it suddenly hangs up and requests timeout and when we restart the server everything works perfectly.

The IIS log gives this error:

> memory exhausted and no new connections

The server is GoDaddy server.

Comment: I guess this memory leak issue in your app

Comment: Not much we can do without error messages or some snippets of code that could be the suspects...

Comment: A memory leak from an unmanaged component is a likely suspect.  What is the application stack?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h

Comment: Check some of the IIS logs. See what pages are being hit, maybe there is one there that has some trouble.